# How to update TextView in parant Activity based on current ImageView in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Im new to android dev and Im currently struggling with this annoying problem for days.
Tried google and many articles. None helped. Also tried IRC for some on line help but couldnt get a straight answer. Maybe you can direct me in the right direction...

My app is basically a ViewPager that holds a single Fragment class. Inside the Fragment class, there is a switch case block that determines based on position, which image to load from the resources folder. The thing is, I have a TextView View in my parent Activity that needs to get updated according to the current picture. Like an image title.
I used:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titleTV);
```

in onCreateView() to get access to that TextView from within the Fragment. And added a:

```
tv.setText("Picture 1");
```

for instance, to the switch case block. This way, when a picture is shown, the text view gets updated.
The problem is, the method that retrieves a new Fragment with each slide, getItem(int position) in the parent Activity, gets called twice to load more than one Fragment to memory. This causes the current position to be one int ahead. Meaning, the switch case stands on case 0 for instance and it shows a specific picture, but the text gets updated from case 1.
I cant get it to work properly because of that. 
What am I doing wrong??

Thank you

Comment: just because you mentioned it's a title and new in Android, you might be interested in checking the PagerTitleStrip (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html)

Comment: ohh! This is interesting. I'll check this out.
Thank you!

Comment: This is close to what I need but not exactly. I managed to implement it, but I get a static text so I tried PagerTabStrip. For a dynamic update. But its still not exactly what I needed.
I'm looking to update a certain TextView at a specific location...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to determine text based on current fragment position only you can use [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). In you Activity implement that interface and use it by calling `mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(SomeOnPageChangeListener)`. Determine what text put into `TextView` with `OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected()` method.

Unfortunately there is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27526) in SDK and onPageSelected() is not called for page at position 0 when it is shown for the first time. You can find workaround under above link, use `ViewPager.setCurrentPage(1)` or just set text for that position manually in `onCreate()` method.

Example code:

```
//activity onCreate()
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                String someText = determineText(position)
                mTextView.setText(someText);

    });

    //because onPageSelected will not be called for page 0 first time
    String someText = determineText(0)
    mTextView.setText(someText);
}

private String determineText(int position){ //static?
    //switch?
}
```

Comment: Ooohh... Alright Ill try this one now !! :)
This is extremely instructional...
I understand that this procedure using an interface to pass the data is some sort of Design Pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll give a piece of code, you can use that, not just for a `String` but for any data at all that you want to send to the Activity from the Fragment, or even from other type of classes between each other.

That's the type of code is also used on .'setOnSomethingHappenListener(listener);'

```
public interface TitleChangeListener{
   public void onTitleChanged(String title);
}
```

then on your activity you will

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements TitleChangeListener{

    @Override
    onTitleChanged(String title){
          // set here your value
    }

}
```

then on your fragment

```
public void MyFragment extends Fragment{

    private TitleChangeListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        if(activity instanceof TitleChangeListener)
            listener = (TitleChangeListener)activity;
        else
            // throw some error ???
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        listener.onTitleChanged("my title");
    }

}
```

and remember I typed all of that by heart, there is bound to have some small mistakes.
But just follow the idea and you'll be fine.

Comment: Alright. So I fixed some of the code to the best of my knowledge.
It now updates the text but it has some sort of long delay. I need to slide 2-3 pictures and only then it updates the text to "my title".
Im missing something... also, how do I determine the appropriate text to present according the the selected picture and not have only "my title" show?

Comment: I just realised the Fragment I wrote `extend Activity` (fixed on the code) and it was `onPause` instead of `onResume()` (also updated on my answer). I would start by checking those.

Comment: Alright! Perfect :)
I changed to onResume and I think it now updates immediately.
So in onResume() I should add something like a switch case to determine the right text to pass? Right now it passes a static "my title" text. Or is this not the right way?

Comment: Alright. I changed the interface method to accept an int position instead of String title. Now onResume() sends an int position as the parameter and the parent Activity knows which position is now selected and I can use a switch case to update the right text. BUT.
It seems that if I slide the ViewPager to the left (or back in essence), the text does not get updated anymore... Its stuck on the last text used. Also if I slide the pictures fast, the text doesnt get updated either... Im sooo clooossee..! :)
Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Thank you Budius!! Lecho's answer hit the spot :)